# Script sharp compilation error

Tags: c#, script#

I create follow class

```
class Class1<T>
{
    private T _d;

    public T GetD()
    {
        return _d;
    }

    public void SetD(T d)
    {
        _d = d;
    }
}
```

and if I tried to compile this class I get the error:

Error   3   Check that your C# source compiles and that you are not using an unsupported feature.

What in my code wrong?

Comment: OOPS!!! didn't see that "script#" tag. ...  Nope, I copy/pasted same code and tried compiling ... It haven't thrown any error. Moreover, I don't see anything wrong with the code. which version of C# you are using ... I tried in C# 2005.

Answer (score 1):

Generics are not supported by ScriptSharp: http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/Conceptual-Understanding